# Unable to use @Autowired in a unit test in a spring project

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have a spring project in Java.
In the project, I have a Kafka configuration class and an additional class that uses the Kafka templets and performs some logic.
I am trying to create a unit test to verify my logic but I am not able to `@Autowire` the class in the test class.
Here are my classes:
Kafka configuration

```
@Configuration
@Getter
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:realtime.properties")
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
    @Value("${kafka.producer.client.id}")
    private String producerClientId;
    @Value("${kafka.url}")
    private String kafkaUrl;
    @Value("${kafka.retries.config}")
    private int retryConfig;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<Void, SomeClass1> producerFactory1() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaUrl);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, producerClientId.concat("_someClass1"));
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, retryConfig);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, VoidSerializer.class.getName());
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, AvroSerde.serializerFor(SomeClass1.class));

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<Void, SomeClass1> kafkaTemplate1() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory1());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<Void, someClass2> producerFactory2() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaUrl);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, producerClientId.concat("_someClass2"));
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, retryConfig);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, VoidSerializer.class.getName());
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, AvroSerde.serializerFor(someClass2.class));

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<Void, someClass2> kafkaTemplate2() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory2());
    }

}
```

The class who uses Kafka configuration:

```
@Component
public class FilterPublisher {
    private final String SERVICE_NAME = "some-service";

    @Value("${kafka.notification.topic}")
    private String notificationTopic;
    @Value("${kafka.tracing.topic}")
    private String tracingTopic;
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<Void, someClass1> kafkaTemplate1;
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<Void, someClass2> kafkaTemplate2;

    public FilterPublisher() {
    }

    public void doSomeLogic() {
        // do something ...
    }

    private void publishToKafka() {
        // do something ....
    }

}
```

The unit test class:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {FilterPublisher.class, KafkaProducerConfig.class})
public class FilterPublisherTest {
    @Autowired
    private FilterPublisher filterPublisher;

    @Test
    public void tmpTest() {
        filterPublisher.processConfigurations();
    }
}
```

When running the test, `filterPublisher` is always null.
What am I missing? what am I doing wrong? how do I fix it?

I also tried using the import annotation on the test class `@Import(TestConfig.class)`

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterPublisher filterPublisher() {
        return new FilterPublisher();
    }

}
```

but the result was the same.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you're not supposed to autowire the class you are trying to test. You instantiate it, mock any members, and test it

Comment: You are importing KafkaProducerConfig that probably do not scan for that component (add the right component scan to that class will fix your issue). Btw I suggest you to follow @Stultuske advice

Comment: If I just instantiate the class, how would the kafkaTemplates be initiated? The component scan should include the path of the project?

Comment: I've added `@ComponentScan({"com.path.to.kafka", "com.path.to.publisher"})` to the test class and it did not help

Comment: @Dan they should be mocked. Do you know how mocking works?

Comment: I have some idea. But since I don't usually work with spring (actually never, I am doing it out of necessity) I am not 100% sure. Basically, you create a dummy object and you specify what it should return upon certain method execution.

Comment: @Dan indeed, and it's not Spring related, so whether you usually work with Spring or not, shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working,
here is the code for the Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {FilterPublisher.class, KafkaProducerConfig.class})
public class FilterPublisherTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    FilterPublisher filterPublisher;

     // ALL TEST METHODS GO HERE

}
```